# My products' prices keep refreshing between zero and non-zero prices, how do I resolve?

Tags: admin, price, cache, indexing

Under Admin > Attributes,

There are three attributes that were created, Special Price, Start Date, End Date.

For whatever reason, when I remove the price as a blank so that I no longer want to apply a special price to a product, it works - BUT ONLY FOR A MINUTE. Then it defaults to 0.00 and it displays as 0.00 on my product grid and product page when I revisit the product page (as admin).

Any steps I can take as to how I can resolve? Thank you!

I'm running Magento 1.9

Comment: Did you create an attribute named special price? What is its code?